# Application of Definite Integral Question

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

My professor just gave us this challenge problem:

Consider a horizontal cone with vertex at the origin and radius $3$ at $x = 7$. Find the volume of the portion of the cone lying between the planes $x = 2$ and $x = 4$.

Any help? I would love to impress them.

Comment: What tools do you have at your disposal? Are you familiar with the cylindrical shell method or the washer method? Either approach would work well here.

Comment: Why would anyone use Calculus to find this volume, when geometry gives you a formula for the volume of a cone, given the height and radius of the base?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line passing through (0,0),(7,3) is described by $y=\frac{3}{7}x$.

By the washer method: $$V=\pi\int_2^4\left[\frac{3}{7}x\right]^2 dx=\frac{9\pi}{49}\cdot\frac{1}{3}x^3\Big|^4_2=\frac{3\pi}{49}(64-8)=\frac{24\pi}{7}$$

Comment: Thank you so much for your clear explanation!  This helps!